# MongoDB filter with composite object

Tags: mongodb

Imagine having a MongoDB collection with this "schema":

```
mycollection: {
    name: String
    treatments: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        colors: ObjectId[]
    }]
}
```

and have a couple of record like this

```
{
    name: "Foo",
    treatments:[
        { type: ObjectId('123456'), colors: [ObjectId('654321')] }
   ]
},
{
    name: "Bar",
    treatments:[
        { type: ObjectId('123456'), colors: [ObjectId('789012')] }
   ]
}
```

If I try to filter those record using:

```
{ "treatments.type": ObjectId('123456'), "treatments.colors": { $in: [ObjectId('654321')] } }
```

I expect that returns only the record with name "Foo", but instead it returns both records, treating  the filter like an OR. Even

```
{ $and: [{ "treatments.type": ObjectId('123456') }, { "treatments.colors": { $in: [ObjectId('654321')] } ] }
```

returns the same.

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated ❤️

Comment: Do you use `find` or `aggregate`?

Comment: I use `find` to perform the lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use elemMatch in mongodb this will find the element from array which has both the condition true

```
{ treatments: { $elemMatch: { type: ObjectId('123456'), colors: { $in: [ObjectId('654321')] } } } }
```

otherwise it is default behaviour in mongodb that when specifying conditions on more than one field nested in an array of documents, you can specify the query such that either a single document meets these condition or any combination of documents (including a single document) in the array meets the conditions.
check this link for further explanation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: Thanks a lot, not just for the answer but for the explanation and useful link. I can't find it myself due to the lack of words to find the right pointer. I learned twice today so thanks again